# Run function when press on back button - android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I want to run a function by pressing the back button of `Android`

I use in PhoneGap - 2.2.0 : [**BackButtonEvent**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton",RunBack, false);

function RunBack() {
    alert('RunBack');
}
```

also:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {RunBack();}, false);
```

also:

```
document.addEventListener("backKeyDown", function (e) {RunBack();}, false);
```

**Why is it not working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
// This is your app's init method. 
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDR, false);
} 

function onDR(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
}

function backKeyDown() {
    // do something
}
```

See this thread for more details:

[Capturing back key press on PhoneGap for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698990/capturing-back-key-press-on-phonegap-for-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks it worked!! The problem was that I did not put the addEventListener in deviceready